# Detect currently open mailitem when ribbon button is clicked

Tags: c++, outlook, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook addin, when a button is clicked and multiple mail items are open in fullview (double click/full open), I can't detect which mailitem was active when user clicked my toolbar/ribbon button. How can I detect it?

Answer (score 0):

`RibbonControl.Context` (`RibbonControl` is passed to your click even handler) will point to an `Inspector` object. Use `Inspector.Cur`rentItem.